# Robin Herbots vs Igor Escobar Input Mask

Tags: jquery-inputmask

I'm troubled about this two Input Masks and I couldn't decide which one to use.
Any comments from more experienced fellows?

Source:

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created the jQuery Mask Plugin because I needed something more flexible and extensible. That is the main difference to me. It's hosted by several CDNs, dependency managers and it's compatible with most popular frameworks. If you are having problems don't hesitate on opening an issue for us on GitHub you are more than welcome.

Comment: Hi Igor! I'm learning both, and for me they both work nicely. Just want to see if there is any cons to each.